# No elements found when using BeatifulSoup find_all

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Hi community :)**

I am a bit stuck with my project. I try to scrape the news from the websites https://mercomindia.com/category/solar/?_page=1 and https://www.pv-magazine.com/news/page/2/ with BeautifulSoup.

BS4 is working correctly, I used my code already for multiple other websites but in these two cases (especially pv-magazine is very valuable to me), I do not find any html-tags.
I use the find_all to find the date tags and a href tags but my lists are always empty. I tried to change it from html5lib to htmlparser, tried to change the tags but nothing seems to work.
Anyone got a clue, what's wrong?

Here's my code:

```
dates = []
news_bodies = []

# Capture the news from this url

scrape_url = 'https://mercomindia.com/category/solar/?_page=1'

# Parsing the HTML
r1 = requests.get(scrape_url)
page = r1.content

# Using Beatifulsoup to get the content of the correct HTML attributes
page_soup = soup(page, 'html.parser')

dates_soup = page_soup.find_all('span',{'class':'entry-date'})
titles_soup = page_soup.find_all('a',{'class':'_self cvplbd'})

for i in range (0, len(dates_soup)):
    corpus = ""
    time.sleep(.1) # Prevents site spam
    dates.append(dates_soup[i].time['text'])
    news_url = titles_soup[i]['href']
    r2 = requests.get(news_url)
    news_page = r2.content
    news_page_soup = soup(news_page, 'html.parser')
    news_text = news_page_soup.find_all('p')
    for news in news_text:
        if (("<!--" in news.text) == False):
            text_p_tag = news.text.replace("\n", " ").replace("\t", " ") 
            if (("staff reporter" in text_p_tag) == True):
                break                
            corpus += text_p_tag
    news_bodies.append(corpus)
```

Comment: You have a problem with the `dates_soup` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass relevant headers in order to get proper html response. Pass User Agent in the headers.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

dates = []
hrefs = []


# Capture the news from this url

scrape_url = 'https://mercomindia.com/category/solar/?_page=1'

headers = {'user-agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

# Parsing the HTML
r1 = requests.get(scrape_url, headers=headers)
page = r1.content

# Using Beatifulsoup to get the content of the correct HTML attributes
page_soup = soup(page, 'html.parser')

divs = page_soup.find("div",{"data-id":"pt-cv-page-1"}).find_all("div", class_="pt-cv-content-item")

for div in divs:
    hrefs.append(div.find("a")["href"])
    dates.append(div.find("span",class_="entry-date").get_text(strip=True))

print(dates)
print("-"*10)
print(hrefs)
```

Output:

```
['August 13, 2020', 'August 13, 2020', 'August 13, 2020', 'August 13, 2020', 'August 13, 2020', 'August 13, 2020', 'August 13, 2020', 'August 12, 2020', 'August 12, 2020', 'August 12, 2020', 'August 12, 2020', 'August 11, 2020', 'August 11, 2020', 'August 10, 2020', 'August 8, 2020', 'August 7, 2020', 'August 7, 2020', 'August 7, 2020', 'August 7, 2020', 'August 7, 2020', 'August 6, 2020', 'August 6, 2020', 'August 6, 2020', 'August 6, 2020', 'August 6, 2020']
----------
['https://mercomindia.com/winners-gujarat-solar-auction/', 'https://mercomindia.com/bescom-issues-amendment/', 'https://mercomindia.com/ireland-lists-solar-wind-projects/', 'https://mercomindia.com/tata-power-registers-profits/', 'https://mercomindia.com/european-union-extends-countervailing-duty/', 'https://mercomindia.com/south-africa-sasol-invites-bids-solar/', 'https://mercomindia.com/power-finance-loans-solar-developer/', 'https://mercomindia.com/eesl-tender-solar-projects-maharashtra/', 'https://mercomindia.com/tender-reissued-25-mw/', 'https://mercomindia.com/gujarat-new-industrial-policy-solar/', 'https://mercomindia.com/interested-parties-solar-glass-imports/', 'https://mercomindia.com/eib-engie-off-grid-solar-uganda/', 'https://mercomindia.com/eesl-empanel-consultants-solar-projects/', 'https://mercomindia.com/reil-tenders-multicrystalline-solar-cells/', 'https://mercomindia.com/french-technique-solaire-expand-portfolio/', 'https://mercomindia.com/actis-acquires-solar-projects-acme/', 'https://mercomindia.com/renesola-power-raises-12-million/', 'https://mercomindia.com/andhra-waives-stamp-duty-solar/', 'https://mercomindia.com/cerc-approves-tariffs-solar-projects/', 'https://mercomindia.com/ayana-renewable-acquires-two-solar-projects/', 'https://mercomindia.com/amp-energy-tata-azure-o2-power-ntpc-solar-auction/', 'https://mercomindia.com/no-ists-charges-solar-wind-projects/', 'https://mercomindia.com/another-deadline-extension-renewable-power/', 'https://mercomindia.com/long-term-bcd-india-solar-roundtable/', 'https://mercomindia.com/central-electronics-bids-solar-ribbons/']
```

Answer (score 1):

To fixe the issue of `dates_soup` empty list

This will solve it:

```
dates=[]
date=[]
for tag in soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'entry-date'}):
    for anchor in tag.find_all('time'):
        date.append(anchor.get_text())


for i in range (0, len(date)):
    print(date[i])
    corpus = ""
    time.sleep(.1) # Prevents site spam
    dates.append(date[i])
    news_url = titles_soup[i]['href']
```

And Also it's better to use headers to prevent getting response error (like `403 Forbidden`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site= "https://mercomindia.com/category/solar/?_page=1"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print(soup)
```